# Lefthook error: flutter command not found

Tags: flutter, hook, atlassian-sourcetree

I switched from GitHub Desktop to Sourcetree due to some missing feature.

On my flutter project, I installed LeftHook to execute a linter when someone commits something.
On GitHub Desktop, Lefthook works well, but when I try to commit from SourceTree, the  error `sh: flutter: command not found`

[image: Error]

I can't understand why. The flutter SDK path is set globally correctly (i can use flutter commands in every terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Seems like that Sourcetree isn't capable to access to the `PATH` in witch flutter is contained (the one added in the file .zshrc).
So the solution is to add the export in every hook that lefthook uses,
something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/.../flutter/bin"

if [ "$LEFTHOOK" = "0" ]; then
...
```

Comment: This doesn't really work because left hook occasionally overwrites the scripts  in .git/hooks folder